# Android: can i have round border around on my image

Tags: java, android, image, border, crop

i was successful in cropping image with round shape. but now i want to add round Red border programmatically around it.
i tried many things to play with the code i have but its not working.
here is the code of the class which does the cropping

```
enter code here

import android.R.color;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;

/**
 * GraphicsUtil an utility class which convert the image in circular shape
 */
 public class GraphicsUtil {

/*
 * Draw image in circular shape Note: change the pixel size if you want
 * image small or large
 */

  public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int targetWidth = 400;
    int targetHeight = 400;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth) / 2, ((float) targetHeight) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CW);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    // paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color.white);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), paint);
    // paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
            sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth,
            targetHeight), paint);

    return targetBitmap;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for rounded border around the image, this function shows rounded image along with border to the imageview

```
public Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffffffff;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 4);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: yea i tried this code. problem with this is i cannot change the output image size and the main thing is still i don't get the border around the image